# selectable shapes (circle/rect) in google maps api (v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I made a google map where you can draw cirles/rectangles using the drawing manager or using custom 'draw circle' and 'draw rectangle' buttons as in the example on 
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html

however on this example the shapes can be selected and then deleted in my version this isn't possible; all shapes are always selected and i can't find anything in the documentation?

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawCircle(){
        console.log("Drawing Circle on Map");
        var circleOptions = {
            <!--draw the circle in the center of the viewport-->
            center : (map.getCenter()),
            radius : 1000000,
            map: map,
            editable: true,
            clickable:true
        };

        circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
        return false;
    }

    function drawRectangle(){
        console.log("Drawing Rectangle on Map");
        var rectOptions = {
            <!--draw the circle in the center of the viewport-->
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            radius : 1000000,
            map: map,
            editable: true,
            clickable:true
        };

        rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(rectOptions);
        return false;
    }

    function showDrawingManager(){
        var managerOptions = {
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER, google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
            },
            markerOptions: {
                editable: true
            },
            circleOptions: {
                editable: true
            },
            rectangleOptions: {
                editable : true
            }
        }

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager(managerOptions);
        drawingManager.setMap(map); 
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to delete the shapes?

Comment: I haven't written that yet :p i'll do it when it's done

Comment: Well the problem that I see is that you have no aggregation for the circles or rectangles you create, leaving you with no means to reference them. As with multiple map markers, append each of them to an array and then use googles shape event handlers to manage what happens to each individual shape.

Comment: ok thx; I found a nice example at if anyone else is interested http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html

Answer (score 2):

this is better :
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_DrawingTools_deleteAll.html

Comment: Could you add an explanation with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a question where a circle/polygon when drawn is attached with a Delete Button  ( X mark ). Clicking it will delete the shape it is attached to.

[Drawing Circles / Polygons With Individual Delete Buttons in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586442/drawing-circles-polygons-with-individual-delete-buttons-in-google-maps-api-v3/45586443#45586443)