# Drawing Circles / Polygons With Individual Delete Buttons in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry, google-maps-markers

This is to help people who have been trying to implement this or have been looking for this solution like I did for quite some time. Not being successful at finding an existing solution, I finally decided to do it.

**How to add a Delete Button or a X mark to a drawn shape (circle / polygon) so that individual shapes can be deleted using this button?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Github Link](https://gist.github.com/loyalvares/c4ba7420b1eb055b309ab48bdcd34219) to view the library and also a complete working example.

On drawing a circle, a delete button (X mark) would be placed at 45 degrees (north-east) on the circle circumference.
For polygons, since they can be unpredictable, I am placing the delete button(X mark) next to the polygon's first vertex.

You can either delete individual circles/polygons or Clear all shapes drawn.

To directly call the library in your HTML file use the following script, 
`<script src="https://gist.github.com/loyalvares/c4ba7420b1eb055b309ab48bdcd34219.js"></script>`

This is the [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/foobarbazz/vn763fu7/) to the same.

```js
/*
     * Method that is called when Google Maps API is loaded.
     */
    function initMap() {
     setInitialMapOptions();
     map = getMapObject(mapOptions);
     drawingManager = getDrawingManagerObject();
     google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', onOverlayComplete);
     initializeDeleteOverlayButtonLibrary();
    }

    // Get Map Geo Center Denver, USA Coordinates
    var center = {lat: 39.810866, lng: -104.990347};
    var map, drawingManager, mapOptions = {};
    var listenerFiltersApplied = false;
    var overlays = {};
    var circleOptions = {
            fillColor: "#e20000",
            fillOpacity: 0,
            strokeColor: "#e20000",
            strokeWeight: 4,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            suppressUndo: true,
            zIndex: 999
       };
    var polygonOptions = {
      editable: true,
      fillColor: "#e20000",
            fillOpacity: 0,
      strokeColor: "#e20000",
      strokeWeight: 4,
         strokeOpacity: 1,
         suppressUndo: true,
         zIndex: 999
     };

    function setInitialMapOptions() {
     mapOptions = {
       zoom: 4,
       center: center,
       styles: [
        {"featureType":"road", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]}, //turns off roads geometry
        {"featureType":"road", elementType:"labels", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]}, //turns off roads labels
        {"featureType":"poi", elementType:"labels", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]},  //turns off points of interest lines
        {"featureType":"poi", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]},  //turns off points of interest geometry
        {"featureType":"transit", elementType:"labels", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]},  //turns off transit lines labels
        {"featureType":"transit", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]}, //turns off transit lines geometry
        {"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel", elementType:"labels", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]},  //turns off administrative land parcel labels
        {"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{visibility:"off"}]},  //turns off administrative land parcel geometry
        {"featureType":"water", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{color: '#d1e1ff'}]},  //sets water color to a very light blue
        {"featureType":"landscape", elementType:"geometry", stylers: [{color: '#fffffa'}]},  //sets landscape color to a light white color
        ],
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
         style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
        },
        minZoom: 2
     };
    }

    function getMapObject(mapOptions) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        return map;
    }

    function getDrawingManagerObject(drawingManagerOptions) {
     var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: null,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [
               google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
               google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
           ]
            },
            circleOptions: circleOptions,
            polygonOptions: polygonOptions
          });
          drawingManager.setMap(map);
          return drawingManager;
    }

    /* -- Overlay Functions Begin Here -- */
    function onOverlayComplete(shape) {
     addDeleteButtonToOverlay(shape);
     addOverlayListeners(shape);
     if(listenerFiltersApplied) {
      listenerFiltersApplied = false;
     }
    }

    function addOverlayListeners(shape) {
     // Filters already applied.
     if(listenerFiltersApplied) {
      return;
     }
     if (shape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      setBoundsChangedListener(shape);
     } 
     if (shape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
      setCenterChangedListener(shape);
      setRadiusChangedListener(shape);
     }
    }

    function setBoundsChangedListener(shape) {
     // Add listeners for each path of the polygon.
     shape.overlay.getPaths().forEach(function(path, index){
      // New point
      google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(){
       listenerFiltersApplied = true;
       onOverlayComplete(shape);
      });
      // Point was removed
      google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'remove_at', function(){
       listenerFiltersApplied = true;
       onOverlayComplete(shape);
      });
      // Point was moved
      google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(){
       listenerFiltersApplied = true;
       onOverlayComplete(shape);
      });
     });
    }

    function setCenterChangedListener(shape) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(shape.overlay, 'center_changed', function() {
      listenerFiltersApplied = true;
      onOverlayComplete(shape);
     });
    }

    function setRadiusChangedListener(shape) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(shape.overlay, 'radius_changed', function() {
      listenerFiltersApplied = true;
      onOverlayComplete(shape);
     });
    }

    function addDeleteButtonToOverlay(shape) {
     var deleteOverlayButton = new DeleteOverlayButton();
     if(("deleteButton" in shape) && (shape.deleteButton != null)) {
      shape.deleteButton.div.remove();
      shape.deleteButton = deleteOverlayButton;
     } else {
      shape.deleteButton = deleteOverlayButton;
     }
     if(shape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
      var radiusInKms = convertDistance(Math.round(shape.overlay.getRadius()), "metres", "kms");
      var circleCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(shape.overlay.getCenter().lat(), shape.overlay.getCenter().lng());
      var deleteOverlayButtonPosition = circleCenter.destinationPoint(30, radiusInKms);
      deleteOverlayButton.open(map, deleteOverlayButtonPosition, shape);
     } else if (shape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      deleteOverlayButton.open(map, shape.overlay.getPath().getArray()[0], shape);
     }
      
      if (!('uid' in shape)) {
      shape.uid = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36);
     }
     overlays[shape.uid] = shape;
    }

    function clearAllOverlays() {
     for(var shapeId in overlays) {
      if(overlays.hasOwnProperty(shapeId)) {
       var shape = overlays[shapeId];
       if(("deleteButton" in shape) && (shape.deleteButton != null)) {
        shape.deleteButton.div.remove();
       }
       shape.overlay.setMap(null);
      }
     }
     overlays = {};
    }

    /*
     * Add any code that needs to be run or cleaned up in this method. 
     * This method is called in DeleteOverlayButton.removeShape().
     */
    function callOnDelete(shape) {
     if(shape['uid'] in overlays) {
      delete overlays[shape['uid']];
     }
    }
    /* -- Overlay Functions End Here -- */

    function convertDistance(distanceValue, actualDistanceUnit, expectedDistanceUnit) {
     var distanceInKms = 0;
     switch(actualDistanceUnit) {
      case "miles":
       distanceInKms = distanceValue/0.62137;
       break;
      case "kms":
       distanceInKms = distanceValue;
       break;
      case "metres":
       distanceInKms = distanceValue/1000;
       break;
      default:
       distanceInKms = undefined;
     }
     
     switch(expectedDistanceUnit) {
      case "miles":
       return distanceInKms * 0.62137;
      case "kms":
       return distanceInKms;
      case "metres":
       return distanceInKms * 1000;
      default:
       return undefined;
     }
    }


    /* ***** Custom Library for Delete Overlay Button (Start) ***** */
     
     /**
      * A HTML Button that lets a user delete a component.
      * @constructor
      * @author: Loy Alvares
      */
     function DeleteOverlayButton() {
      this.div = document.createElement('div');
      this.div.id = 'deleteOverlayButton';
      this.div.className = 'deleteOverlayButton';
      this.div.title = 'Delete';
      this.div.innerHTML = '<span id="x">X</span>';
      var button = this;
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div, 'click', function() {
          button.removeShape();
       button.div.remove();
      });
     }
     
     function initializeDeleteOverlayButtonLibrary() {
      
            /* This needs to be initialized by initMap() */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
      
      /**
       * Add component to map.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.onAdd = function() {
       var deleteOverlayButton = this;
       var map = this.getMap();
       this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(this.div);
      };

      /**
       * Clear data.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.onRemove = function() {
       google.maps.event.removeListener(this.divListener_);
       this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
       // Clear data
       this.set('position');
       this.set('overlay');
      };

      /**
       * Deletes an overlay.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.close = function() {
       this.setMap(null);
      };

      /**
       * Displays the Button at the position(in degrees) on the circle's circumference.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.draw = function() {
       var position = this.get('position');
       var projection = this.getProjection();
       if (!position || !projection) {
        return;
       }
       var point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(position);
       this.div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
       this.div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
       if(this.get('overlay').type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
        this.div.style.marginTop = '-16px';
        this.div.style.marginLeft = '0px';
       }
      };

      /**
       * Displays the Button at the position(in degrees) on the circle's circumference.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.open = function(map, deleteOverlayButtonPosition, overlay) {
       this.set('position', deleteOverlayButtonPosition);
       this.set('overlay', overlay);
       this.setMap(map);
       this.draw();
      };

      /**
       * Deletes the shape it is associated with.
       */
      DeleteOverlayButton.prototype.removeShape = function() {
       var position = this.get('position');
       var shape = this.get('overlay');
       if (shape != null) {
        shape.overlay.setMap(null);
            /* Add any cleanup code or any other events in the below method. */
        callOnDelete(shape);
        return;
       }
       this.close();
      };
      
      Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
       return this * Math.PI / 180;
      }

      Number.prototype.toDegrees = function() {
       return this * 180 / Math.PI;
      }

      /* Based the on the Latitude/Longitude spherical geodesy formulae & scripts
         at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
         (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010
      */
      google.maps.LatLng.prototype.destinationPoint = function(bearing, distance) {
       distance = distance / 6371;  
       bearing = bearing.toRadians();
       var latitude1 = this.lat().toRadians(), longitude1 = this.lng().toRadians();
       var latitude2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(latitude1) * Math.cos(distance) + Math.cos(latitude1) * Math.sin(distance) * Math.cos(bearing));
       var longitude2 = longitude1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(distance) * Math.cos(latitude1), Math.cos(distance) - Math.sin(latitude1) * Math.sin(latitude2));
       if (isNaN(latitude2) || isNaN(longitude2)) return null;
       return new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2.toDegrees(), longitude2.toDegrees());
      }
     }

    /* ***** Custom Library for Delete Overlay Button (End) ***** */
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element that contains the map. */
    .map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    /* CSS for the Delete Button. */
    .deleteOverlayButton {
      background: #dee0df;
      color: #000;
      /* font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; */
      font-size: 11.4px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      width: 14px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 1px 0px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      margin-top: 7px;
      margin-left: 8px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .deleteOverlayButton:hover {
      background: #eee;
    }

    #clearOverlays {
      font-family: var(--websiteFont);
      top: 10%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 1%;
      background: rgb(34,55,65);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: white;
      border: 1px solid rgb(34,55,65);
      padding: 2px 6px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <input id='clearOverlays' onclick="clearAllOverlays();" type=button value="Clear Shapes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7MXQvcn_gskiZeZGhhXekqN1zjUX9fVM&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```